# Unable to use canDeActivate or canActivate in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, canactivate

I am trying to use the canDeActivate and canActivate and I am using it as below with Angular 4. I am getting a `no provider error` for the same. What is wrong with the implementation or what is the right way to implement this cleanly and simply.

```
import {ModuleWithProviders, } from '@angular/core';

    import {Routes, RouterModule, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanDeactivate} from '@angular/router';


    import {HomeComponent} from '../home/home.component';

    var x: any = true;

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canDeactivate: [true]},
        {path: 'test', component: HomeComponent, canDeactivate: [x]},

    ];

    export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

    export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Update of the error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for true!
Error: No provider for true!
    at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:71)
    at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:105)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.ts:141)
    at PreActivation.getToken (router.ts:1232)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.ts:1191)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.ts:125)
    at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:71)
    at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:105)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349)
    at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (ng_module_factory.ts:141)
    at PreActivation.getToken (router.ts:1232)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.ts:1191)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.ts:125)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:769)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:740)
    at zone.js:817
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:253)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:584)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:490)
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: `canDeactivate` takes a function or a class reference

Comment: @Sajeetharan - no provider error

Comment: @Maximus - I tried with an function as described in Angular docs and it is giving token error. Any simple example that you can refer me to?

Comment: @Gary you seem not to accept my answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All guards take a token which refers to a function or a class reference. Here is the simple example for a function as a guard:

```
 // create a token
 const token = new InjectionToken('name');

 // register the provider by that token
 providers: [{provide: token, useValue: function() {} }]

 // use this token in a guard
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
     {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canDeactivate: [token]},
 ];
```

Often times you don't create a token explicitly, but it's created by the reference to the class when you use it like this:

```
@Injectable()
class CanActivateContacts {
    constructor() {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)

@NgModule({
    providers: [CanActivateContacts] <------ token is implicitly created here
})
class AppModule

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canDeactivate: [CanActivateContacts]},
];
```

Comment: Awesome. I did not realise the InjectionToken was needed. I remember it working without a token before and directly with a boolean here. Am I wrong here? Thank you. You score with one line or one blog :-)

Comment: @Gary, I added some more info to the answer where the token is created implicitly. What did you mean here _You score with one line or one blog_? :) I'm not a native speaker

Comment: You have keen eyes.

Comment: for this `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)` isnt it supposed to be ` {path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateContacts]},`

Comment: can you clarify? I don't quite understand. `canActivate` is a method on a class

Comment: When you use interface canactivate isnt it supposed to be used for canactivate in route?

Comment: @Gary, no, interface has no runtime value. I removed it from the answer so you don't get confused. You should specify a token in a route be it an InjectionToken instance or a class reference. Whatever you registered in a providers array

Comment: Thanks Maximus. I believe all the variations using this method works!! Thanks...  :-)